# How to install PPAs (from Launchpad) on non-Ubuntu distros like Debian?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, software-installation, package-management, ppa

AFAIK only Ubuntu and (obviously) Ubuntu-based distributions can handle  [PPA](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PPA)s. A major (and maybe the only) source of PPAs is Launchpad - another service by Canonical.

A real-world example is [Notepadqq](http://notepadqq.altervista.org/wp/download/). They only provide installation via PPA/Launchpad.

So how can I install them on non-Ubuntu distros like Debian? Can I probably download them (as a `.deb` file or something similar) manually from the Launchpad site?

Comment: For this particular example, I would recommend using the source at https://github.com/notepadqq/notepadqq manually. You should always be able to install an open-source project... well, from source, regardless of how binary packaging is done.

Comment: Thanks. I did not knew their source is on GitHub. And there they also link to Debian builds downloadable from Launchpad. :smile:

Answer (score 2):

You can run this command in Debian Wheezy and newer:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
```

Now, you can use `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:some/ppa` in Debian!

**HOWEVER!**

It will not find any packages for you! This is because it is looking for **Debian** packages, but PPAs hold **Ubuntu** packages. You need to edit the files located in:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/YOURPPA/YOURPPA.list
```

And replace all **DEBIAN VERSION** occurrences with an Ubuntu version, I suggest **Trusty** as it is currently the most recent LTS version of Ubuntu.

Now, you can run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install YOURPACKAGE
```

To install the package from the PPA.

Source: [WebUpd8 Team](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/10/how-to-add-launchpad-ppas-in-debian-via.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your example - **Notepadqq** - installed to **Debian 10.0.0 Buster**.

Although Ubuntu-oriented, in fact the official [notepadqq PPA repository](https://launchpad.net/~notepadqq-team/+archive/ubuntu/notepadqq) does contain .deb files!

(I chose Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic from the *technical details* dropdown.)

Download both of the following .deb files:

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/notepadqq-team/notepadqq/ubuntu/pool/main/n/notepadqq/notepadqq-common_1.4.4-1~bionic1_all.deb
http://ppa.launchpad.net/notepadqq-team/notepadqq/ubuntu/pool/main/n/notepadqq/notepadqq_1.4.4-1~bionic1_amd64.deb
```

Install via terminal as follows:

```
sudo dpkg -i ./notepadqq-common_1.4.4-1~bionic1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install -f

sudo dpkg -i ./notepadqq_1.4.4-1~bionic1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Success! ( See: /usr/share/applications/notepadqq.desktop)